# How to Hide any or all column header in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, header, hide

I am currently working on a Windows App using C#. I have this datagridview whose first image columns are Edit and Delete. I have an issue with hiding both their headers. How can I do that, yet keep the headers of the following columns visible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't believe there is no elegant way of hiding a column header yet even after 9 years that this question had been asked!

Answer (score 7):

While Using C# you can write the following

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["CustomerID"].Visible = false;
```

and to Hide all the column headings you can use:

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Select the datagridview and open property, there in property list you can set it to false like mentioned in screenshot .

[image: ScreenShot]

In your filename.cs file you can add something like this..

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
```

in your filename.Designer.cs file you will have ..

```
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

For C# Winforms,

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
```

For asp.net (reader looking for a web solution)

```
dataGridView1.ShowHeader = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide all the column headers

```
dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
```

Hide specific column header

```
dataGridView.Columns[4].Name = "Delete"; //Add name you want
dataGridView.Columns[4].HeaderText = "";
```

I added a column name and then I put column header text as empty. But I able to work with column name if it is not visible. This is works for me.